What is "free" and what is "interacting" in the interaction picture?
How do we rigorously and systematically discern between the "free" and the "interacting" part of a Hamiltonian? That is, how can we find $\hat{H}_{\text{free}}$ and $\hat{H}_{\text{int}}$ such that we get the following?
$$\hat{H} = \hat{H}_{\text{free}} + \hat{H}_{\text{int}}.$$
In general, it seems that there is a tacit algorithm to know if $\hat{H}_{\text{free}}$ is really free or interacting, which basically boils down to having linear equations of motion. This means that

It must be true that the second derivative with respect to the field is a constant independent of the field $\phi$ in order for it not to be self-interacting

$$\frac{\partial^3 \hat{H}_{\text{free}}}{\partial \phi^3} = 0 \qquad \forall \phi,$$

It must also be true that the derivative with respect to any field $\phi$ does not depend on any other field $\psi$ in order for it not to be interacting

$$\frac{\partial^2 \hat{H}_{\text{free}}}{\partial \psi \partial \phi} = 0 \qquad \forall \psi, \phi : \psi \neq \phi.$$
Are these two conditions correct? Could we consider a term of the Hamiltonian as "free" even if these two conditions are not satisfied?

Any Hamiltonian that's not free is interacting, and I know a free Hamiltonian when I see it ;)

For a free massive particle field, the free hamiltonian includes a self interacting term, the mass one.

@PatoGalmarini but it produces a set of linear equations of motion. It fulfills both of the conditions I gave, and thus there would be no problem in considering it part of a free Hamiltonian. Other wording may be appropriate to refer to the first condition of "non-self-interactivity", but I don't know how else to call it.

@ACuriousMind based on intuition and sight it is generally easy to see a free Hamiltonian, but a mathematical algorithm would be increadibly helpful and even necessary to attain full rigor.

Free hamiltonians are quadratic, interacting terms are cubic or of higher order in the fields.

I guess we could call $\hat{H}_\text{free}$ anything that we know the exact solution of. This will act as your zero step for the perturbative expansion.

Your second condition should be that the first derivative (not second derivative) does not depend on any other field.  If the field is multiplied by any other field in the Hamiltonian, then it is not free.
Another way to state the condition for a free Hamiltonian is this:  when you write the Hamiltonian in terms of particle creation and annihilation operators, it is a free Hamiltonian if it is a linear combination of particle number operators.

Ooops, that's completely true. It's already updated. Many thanks for the response!
